# Macbook Air 2013 won't wake after opening lid 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, suspend, macbook, lid

I've got a 13" mid-2013 MacBook Air, and I'm dual booting OSx and Xubuntu. Everything seems to be working relatively well except waking the laptop by opening the lid. The screen lights up to the login screen for just under a second, and then disappears. No keyboard commands will wake it, my brightness doesn't change either. I have to hold the power button and reboot to get back into the OS. Does anybody have any idea how I can get this fixed?